# Adding AJAX to a Telerik PanelBar? (Expand and Contract Items)

Tags: ajax, telerik, accordion, panel

I am currently trying to Ajaxify a Rad PanelBar. By adding False Panels to the inside's of each PanelBarItem I have managed to achieve MOST of what I want to achieve with AJAX in the PanelBar. But unfortunately I am having trouble switching from one PanelBarItem to another Using AJAX.

My end goal is to:

- Have the end user hit a button which fires a method which dynamically creates a report
- Close the current PanelBarItem they are in (PanelBarItem_01)
- Show that Report in a ReportViewer located in PanelBarItem_02
- Expand PanelBarItem_02 to show the Report

This all works fine with a Full Postback, but it runs quite choppy, and frankly it's just too slow. I have already tried applying my RadAjaxManagerProxy, UpdatedControls to the WHOLE PanelBar itself, but no luck.

Is it possible to Expand and Contract RadPanelBarItems using Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speed up the performance, load the items in the expanded panelbar items only and hide the rest with visible = false dynamically. Also you may use RadCompression to reduce the packets transferred between the client and the server. Hope these tips are useful.